# Dependency Injection in Unit Test for Eclipse 4 RCP App

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

In my Unit Test I want to access a Part to check whether some UI Components exist. The constructor of the Part uses dependency injection and for some Tests the partService should be "real" and not mocked:

```
@Inject
public MyPart(EPartService partService) {
    ...
}
```

In the TestCase I want to Access/create the Part. I tried several things and have some questions about what to do. My first trys in the TestCase look like this:

```
@Test
public void testAGlobalVariableShouldBeAddableToTheUi() {
    /* First try
        IEclipseContext context = null;
        context = EclipseContextFactory.create();
        myPart = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyPart.class,context);
    */

    //Second try (Discouraged Access)
    myPart= InjectorFactory.getDefault().make(MyPart.class,null);
}
```

I get an ExceptionInInitializer Exception when I try to run it as a JUnit Test.
I get an "Could not find satisfiable constructor" Exception when I try to run it as an JUnit Plugin Test.

My Questions are:
How do I retrieve/create a Part in an JUnit TestCase?
If I try to run the TestCases as JUnitPlugin Tests, can I get already created Parts?

Edit: 
I also tried

```
try {
    myPart = (MyPart)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("de.mypart");
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

what gives me this Exception:
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Could not create view: de.mypart

Edit:
I tried to mock EPartService as suggested. Then I need to put it in the context. 
I do it like this:

```
context.set(EPartService.class, partService); 
context.set(Composite.class, shell);
```

Eclipse says it cannot find a Composite. I guess it´s the one needed for:

```
@PostConstruct 
public void postConstruct(Composite parent)
```

Do I need to put the Composite in the context differently? And how do I hang my Context into the Context hierarchy?

Comment: Note: You can't use `PlatformUI` at all in an e4 application.

Comment: Your first try doesn't look so bad. You need to mock the EPartService und put it in the context.

Comment: If I mock it, I need to put it in the context. Eclipse then seems to not find the Composite for 
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent)
I set these in my context
    context.set(EPartService.class, partService);
    context.set(Composite.class, shell);

Comment: Okay to add the context to the hierarchy I can use the contexts setParent method. But it still does not find the Composite. Is there a way that I can see how on a normal Application run, Eclipse puts the Object into the context?